# Solving theorem proof with only primitive rules of logic!

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I am having trouble solving the theorem proof of **(P-> ~Q)->(Q->~P)**. I can only use primitive rules and I understand I have to use arrow introduction to introduce my antecedent, but after that I am a bit lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: logic primer by colin allen and michael hand

Answer (score 1):

To Prove: $(P\to \neg Q)\to(Q\to \neg P)$

Assume $P\to\neg Q$ and $Q$, and show this implies $\neg P$ via a contradition.

Then discharge the assumptions in the right order, by two applications of implication-introduction

Comment: I introduced P->~Q and tried to introduce P and Q by means of reductio but kept running into contradictions.

Comment: Yes,.  You are supposed to.   If assuming $P$ with $P\to\neg Q$ and $Q$ infers a contradiction, then ...

Comment: 1 1 P->~Q  A->(1)   then assume P with Reduction which gives me ~Q from arrow elimination then I would assume Q with Reductio which is a contradiction and I can get P from there however how am I supposed to discharge the assumption of Q out of my proof.

Comment: When assuming $Q$ infers $\neg P$, then you have $Q\to \neg P$ by *implication (arrow) introduction*.  This is a way to discharge the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{array}{llll}
1&(1)&P \rightarrow \neg Q&A\\
2&(2)&Q&A\\
3&(3)&P&A\\
1,3&(4)&\neg Q&1,3 \rightarrow E\\
1,2&(5)&\neg P&2,4 \ RAA \ (3)\\
1&(6)&Q \rightarrow \neg P&5 \rightarrow I \ (2)\\
&(7)&(P \rightarrow \neg Q) \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow \neg P)&6 \rightarrow I \ (1)\\
\end{array}

Comment: Minor edit needed on line $(7)$: It should be $6 \rightarrow I \ (1)$.

Comment: @quasi Thanks :)

Comment: @Bram28 (5) is $\neg$-intro, not RAA.

Comment: @KennyLau Most books would indeed call it $\neg$ Intro, but the OP uses the book 'Logic Primer', in which this rule is named RAA

Comment: @Bram28 that is... unfortunate.

Comment: @KennyLau If only I got a nickle for every unfortunate name-use in logic texts .... :)